# Primary view controller not extending under top/bottom bars in split view controller

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

In my app I have a split view controller in a tab bar controller, and the master view controller is embedded inside a navigation controller. Initially the detail view controller is just a blank view controller. Now upon separating from 1 column to 2, the view controller in the primary position is strangely no longer extended under the top and bottom bars. The bars are translucent so you should be able to see the red in the nav and tab bars. I’ve narrowed the problem down to `splitViewController(_:separateSecondaryFrom:)` which I use to embed the detail in a navigation controller. I don’t see why this is causing this behavior in the primary though. What is incorrect with my implementation of this method?

Red appears in the bars as expected in the collapsed interface:
[image]

Upon expanding to two columns the red no longer appears in the bars:
[image]

```
func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, separateSecondaryFrom primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    //in the case where it's separating into two, we want to embed the detail in a navigation controller
    let primaryNavController = primaryViewController as! UINavigationController

    let detailController: UIViewController
    if primaryNavController.viewControllers.count > 1 {
        detailController = primaryNavController.viewControllers[1]
    } else {
        detailController = ViewController()
    }

    return UINavigationController(rootViewController: detailController)
}
```

[I've uploaded a sample project here.](https://d3uepj124s5rcx.cloudfront.net/items/1S3c381g1e432I0g0H2R/SplitMe.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a hiccup in drawing the translucency and blur of the view beneath the bars. May be due to some drawing and caching optimization in the framework but when I triggered the bar hidden and show event on navigation bar, it was fine.

```
func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, separateSecondaryFrom primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    //in the case where it's separating into two, we want to embed the detail in a navigation controller
    let primaryNavController = primaryViewController as! UINavigationController

    let detailController: UIViewController
    if primaryNavController.viewControllers.count > 1 {
        detailController = primaryNavController.viewControllers[1]
    } else {
        detailController = ViewController()
    }
    //Fake trigger to force bars to draw blur translucency
    let navigationNew = UINavigationController(rootViewController: detailController)
    navigationNew.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    navigationNew.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    return navigationNew
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Weird... It works. Can also do `setNeedsLayout()` and `layoutIfNeeded()`. Hmm time to file a bug report.

Comment: Yeah, any event that could trigger the re-draw of navigation view hierarchy should do.